# Bootstrap, how do I add space between my image and text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a image and a text side by side, but now I need to add some spacing between each set of text and image. here my code.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--Row with three equal columns-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content">
        <img src="images/squareicon.png" class="pull-left">
        <h3>Versatile Spaces</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content bg-alt">
        <img src="images/pointericon.png" class="pull-left">
        <h3>Central Location</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content">
        <img src="images/foodicon.png" class="pull-left">
        <h3>Catering to Taste</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your CSS? Specifically the "pull-left" class.

Answer (score 2):

You can give margin to your image:

```
.demo-content img {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: great that fixed the spacing issue, but now the middle column text is not lining up like the rest,i can add &nbsp; but when its in mobile you can see all the spacing.